# Simple jQuery SlideShow Script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transparency, slideshow

I am currently looking for a JavaScript (jQuery) SlideShow Script which allows me to simply have the images fade from one to another, and then keep repeating the process. Nothing too serious, but there is one thing I need specifically for the script. I use .PNG images with Transparency in them, and I have noticed when I use other scripts, they tend to stack upon each other, which shows quite the collboration.

Thank you very much SO,
I appreciate the help!
Aaron

Comment: @Cold: Nevermind my friend, thank you though.

Comment: I was just about to suggest a really killer slide-show plugin but I stopped when I saw your response to Cold Hawaiian.

Comment: @Sparky672: Thank you though Sparky, I was having a problem with the current Slideshow, but I ended up fixing it to an extent, but thank you very much! :-D. @Dmitriy: Thank you! I saw that the question got down-voted, and I have no idea how to resolve my own question, when I had already found the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [jQuery Cycle Lite](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/lite/) plugin, maybe with `sync` disabled.

Also, force images inside the `#slideshow` element to be hidden with `opacity:0` which will be overridden by inline CSS the plugin sets. However, that said it looks like the plugin sets the `opacity` to `0` by default for the all images except the current.

**CSS:**

```
#slideshow img { opacity:0 }
```

**JS:**

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({ sync:0 });
```

Comment: Thank you very much Marcel! I appreciate it very much so!

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to post a link to the simplest slideshow in case others are searching for an easy way to rotate through a list of images in a div and don't need any other functionality using only jQuery...

---

http://jsfiddle.net/DaveAlger/eNxuJ/1/

---

enjoy!